# unable to call two functions on javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript

I want to call two javascript functions, for this i am using

```
<input type="submit" values="submit" onclick="return mandatoryCheck(); submitScore();">
```

But `submitScore()` function didn't execute.
Need help...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are performing some validation check in `mandatoryCheck()` and its returning `true/false`. You should use `&&` operator

*Use*

```
<input type="submit" values="submit" onclick="return mandatoryCheck() && submitScore();">
```

Comment: This will only call the first one if it returns a falsy value.

Comment: @TomDDD, Yes that's my assumption as name suggests that

Comment: mandatoryCheck() function is returning boolean and I want to execute submitScore() function only if mandatoryCheck() returns true.

Comment: @VikasThakur, thats exactly it will do

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd function is unreachable because of the return.

```
<input type="submit" values="submit" onclick="mandatoryCheck(); submitScore();">
```

Comment: @Vikas: we can't help you with that little information. If can sure ensure you that both functions will be called, assuming that no runtime error occurs. So, whatever it is that "doesn't work" must be because of what the functions are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Add semi-colons ; to the end of the function calls in order for them both to work.

```
<input type="submit" values="submit" onclick="mandatoryCheck(); submitScore();">
```

Here is a good reference from SitePoint http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onclick

Answer (score 0):

Using `return` inside of a function (in this case, the onclick is a function) will essential "stop" anything past the return statement to happen.

For instance:

```
var example = function(){
  return true;
  console.log("Hello.")
}
```

That will never log because the function returned a value before the other `console.log()` function could be reached...

That being said, you should redesign your function like this:

```
onclick="mandatoryCheck(); submitScore();"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, `selectJQgridRow()` was not working. My input was like:

```
<input type="button" values="Check" onclick="mandatoryCheck(); selectJQgridRow();">
```

The JavaScript functions were in a separated JavaScript file.
The problem was in the functions definition time.
I had to create `selectJQgridRow()` after the jQgrid table definition. I just put it the last and done.